# pre-release tests on buildfarm

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just went over the tutorials for pre-release tests on the website:

http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest

It refers to the possibility of running pre-release tests on the buildfarm, i.e. non-locally. However, the link pointing to the buildfarm's pre-release page is broken:

"Then go to buildfarm's pre-release web site:
wiki.ros.org/prerelease.ros.org "

Is this feature deprecated? If yes, oh no! Is this feature not available, yet?  If yes, I can't wait. If the feature is around, where can I find the page of the buildfarm's pre-release site? A quick google search did not help me... Thanks already.

Cheers,
Georg.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103596/pre-release-tests-on-buildfarm/) by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated the wiki page with the correct URL http://prerelease.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-11-25**:
Thanks! I'll give it a try. :)